# How to make custom ClassLoader to be returned by .getClassLoader()?

Tags: class, classloader

Need your assistance. I created 2 custom `ClassLoaders` to load class files. But when I try to use .`getClassLoader()` on class I loaded, I saw `ApplicationClassloader` every time.

Answer (score 0):

ClassLoader in Java works on three principle:

1. delegation,
2. visibility
3. uniqueness

   Delegation principle forward request of class loading to parent class loader and only loads the class, if parent is not able to find or load class. Visibility principle allows child class loader to see all the classes loaded by parent ClassLoader, but parent class loader can not see classes loaded by child. Uniqueness principle allows to load a class exactly once, which is basically achieved by delegation and ensures that child ClassLoader doesn't reload the class already loaded by parent.

The class you are trying load should be there in your class path. Please check your application classpath

Read more: [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html#ixzz4kjniev9U)

Answer (score 0):

It means that your class is indeed *defined* by the application class loader, not your custom one. Your custom class loader is just *initiating* class loader that delegates to its parent (application class loader). Make sure the custom class loader defines the class itself.

Comment: yep, I checked this and fixed. Now works properly. Thanks!